# Call a function after router-view in App.vue has been updated due to route change by vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to call a function after the contents in `<router-view/>` in `App.vue` has been updated due to change in a route. I tried using the `updated()` lifecycle hook but the function is not being called.

However, when there is a change in the state outside `<router-view />` within `App.vue` The function is being called. Is there a way to call the function upon change in `<router-view />`

Here is my updated hook's code:

```
updated() {
  console.log("changed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("in timeout");
    store.dispatch("clearGeneralState");
  }, 5000);
},
```

Comment: would like to know this too, watching route, or navigation guards, all seem to be fired before component is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run some code whenever the route changes, you can either

Watch the `$route` object (you can also watch its properties like `$route.path` or `$route.query.someQueryParam` depending on your needs):

```
watch: {
  $route() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Use [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)